# Is it possible to turn mobile data off in XAMARIN app

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I would want my app to only use wifi connection. To achieve this I must either make my app use ONLY wifi (even if the mobile network is on and wifi has no internet connection) or disable mobile network upon starting the app. 
I tried it like that:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.TelephonyService);
            var tdata = tm.DataEnabled;
            if (tdata)
            {
                tdata = false;
                tm.DataEnabled = tdata;
            }
```

but I get the following exception:

```
Java.Lang.SecurityException: 'No Carrier Privilege.'
```

I have read on some posts that andorid no longer supports programaticly in app mobile network switching, but all the posts were a bit old and I couldn't find any up to date data. Is it possible to do this at all?

Comment: It is impossible , we can only detect whether current intent connection is wifi/modible data  but we can't change anything (disable/enable network).